# Immigation USA/Switzerland

Tags: immigration, us-citizens, eu-citizens, switzerland

I am in a long-distance relationship with my girlfriend.
We know that marriage would be the simplest solution, but we would prefer to live together for a longer period before we take this step.
Therefore, we are looking for our possibilities to live together (preferably in Switzerland).

How likely/feasible are the following options we read about:

- A work visa for Switzerland as an archivist.
- The [trainee exchange agreement](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/arbeit/berufspraktikum.html) between the US and Switzerland.

Or does someone has another idea? Financially there shouldn't be issues (My salary is enough to support an average lifestyle for two people in Switzerland).

Job/Education:

She (26) is currently finishing her two Masters in History/Library Science in the USA (She wants to be an archivist and has currently 1 year of experience in this field). She speaks German fluently (C1).
I (24) am currently working full-time as a Software Engineer working for one of the "[Big Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Tech)" in Switzerland. I am also doing a part-time master's in CS. Currently, I have 3 years of experience as a Software Engineer.

Nationality:

She is American. Her grandfather was German, but her mother just had an American citizenship. She already lived in German-speaking countries for more than a year.
I am German with a residential permit for Switzerland. I could apply for the Swiss citizenship right now. I lived in the US for a bit less than a year.

Time range:
We would like to live together after her education (~ 1 year).

Comment: Yes, we know that marriage would be the easiest solution. And all conditions would be satisfied (language level, income, apartment size, ....). But as we just lived together for ~3 months, we would like to live together for a longer period before we decide to take this step (to prevent a misunderstanding, the 3 months relate to the longest time we lived together. We are in a relationship for over a year).

Comment: Is she considering further education? The youth mobility scheme is straightforward *if* she can find an employer for an internship, but that is hard since many employers would simply refuse to consider anyone requiring complicated paperwork; but I don't know enough about her field to assess that. If she can find some postgraduate certificate programs at a Swiss institute, it might be easier especially for future as well if she can get her credentials better recognized by Swiss employers.

Comment: @zhantongz as far as I'm aware US citizens are not eligible for any youth mobility or working holiday visa in Switzerland.

Comment: @phoog It's not a working holiday scheme, but Switzerland allows youth mobility for full-time skilled interns/trainees from USA among other countries, as linked by OP. This type of permit is not subject to quota so it is not hard to obtain if your employer is willing and cooperative (which is not a given).

Comment: This in itself doesn't guarantee a work permit/visa but the first hurdle would be finding a job. She would need one that match her qualifications, from an employer willing to jump through hoops to sponsor them. How does the job market for archivists look in Switzerland?